# Show Tooltip while DataGridView Column is Resized

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, tooltip

I am trying to do a similar effect to Excel when a user resizes a column in a WinForms DataGridView, where a tooltip shows the current size of the column.

Any easy way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this link will helps you.... on how to show a tool tip when the datagridview column is resized...

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/grid/testgridzip.aspx?display=PrintAll

or can you try this..

```
 void dataGridView1_ColumnWidthChanged(object sender,  DataGridViewColumnEventArgs e)
   {
       toolTip1.SetToolTip(dataGridView1.Columns[i].Width.ToString());
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, used this to build my solution. More complicated than I would like but just about works.

Answer (score 0):

My current solution, based on @errorstacks tips.

```
        this.dgvDeskTrades.MouseDown += dgvDeskTrades_MouseDown;
        this.dgvDeskTrades.MouseMove += dgvDeskTrades_MouseMove;
        this.dgvDeskTrades.MouseUp += dgvDeskTrades_MouseUp;

    private int colResizing = -1;
    private int origWidth;
    private int mouseX;

    private void dgvDeskTrades_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        var hit = this.dgvDeskTrades.HitTest(e.X, e.Y);
        if (hit.Type != DataGridViewHitTestType.ColumnHeader) return;
        if (Cursor.Current != Cursors.SizeWE) return;

        this.colResizing = hit.ColumnIndex;
        this.origWidth = this.dgvDeskTrades.Columns[this.colResizing].Width;
        this.mouseX = e.X;
    }

    private void dgvDeskTrades_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.colResizing == -1) return;
        this.dgvDeskTrades.Columns[this.colResizing].Width = Math.Max(0, this.origWidth + (e.X - this.mouseX));
        this.toolTip.Show("Width: " + this.dgvDeskTrades.Columns[this.colResizing].Width, this, e.X, e.Y);
    }

    private void dgvDeskTrades_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.colResizing == -1) return;
        this.toolTip.Hide(this);
        this.colResizing = -1;
    }
```